# Azure Web App Deploy fails with Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Trying to deploy dotnet core 5 app to Azure linux web app from Azure devops.

Building works fine, but the deploy step always fails with this message(some context given):

```
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6172470Z Kudu sync from: '/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6172897Z Copying file: 'web.config'
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6173193Z Finished successfully.
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6173482Z Running post deployment command(s)...
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6173804Z Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6174085Z Deployment successful.
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6174390Z Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6174934Z ##[debug]Deployment Failed with Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6175535Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6204375Z ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6213555Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6216011Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6216735Z ##[debug]Azure_App_Service_Deploy_PackageArtifactAlias=_CPRCard Production Web
2021-11-09T09:53:24.6217280Z ##[debug]release.releaseId=223
```

Im assuming this has something to do with "Runtime stack" or "Startup command" parameters. 1 strange thing is that "Runtime stack" seems to be a dropdown, but there are no values to select from. I tried all sorts of combination of these, empty and with different values, but same result...

[image: Parameters for task]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using this in my `azure-pipelines.yml` file

```
RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|5.0'
StartupCommand: 'dotnet {PROJECT_NAME}.dll'
```

Comment: I assume you meant adding these as variables, I tried, using camelcased version(startUpCommand and runtimeStac), but unfortunately same result in release pipeline. Maybe Im misunderstanding something, but the release part of the pipeline does not have any editable yaml, thats why I assumed you meant adding this to the build yaml