# How to solve this error: "Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined." on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I created a Pipeline which generates an Artifact containing the PHP files of a web app.
Then I created a Release:

[image: Releases]

Stage 1:

[image: Stage 1]

[image: Releases]

```
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8160374Z ##[section]Starting: Azure Web App Deploy: mywebsite-ext
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8311262Z ==============================================================================
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8311557Z Task         : Azure Web App
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8311796Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Web App for Linux or Windows
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8312438Z Version      : 1.195.0
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8312727Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8312966Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurewebapptroubleshooting
2022-01-03T16:50:13.8313251Z ==============================================================================
2022-01-03T16:50:14.3488085Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'mywebsite-ext'
2022-01-03T16:50:14.4249036Z $mywebsite-ext
2022-01-03T16:50:14.4249598Z mywebsite-ext.scm.azurewebsites.net
2022-01-03T16:50:25.4789503Z Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
2022-01-03T16:51:52.8238099Z Deploy logs can be viewed at https://mywebsite-ext.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/21a97ba186f24c17947944f6ae31c124/log
2022-01-03T16:51:52.8239292Z Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
2022-01-03T16:51:52.8283520Z ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
2022-01-03T16:51:57.9260241Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://mywebsite-ext.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/241641228712825
2022-01-03T16:51:57.9261810Z App Service Application URL: http://mywebsite-ext.azurewebsites.net
2022-01-03T16:51:57.9433047Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure Web App Deploy: mywebsite-ext
```

The Azure Web App Service on Linux Files are deployed correctly but Release shows Partially succeeded.
But this error is appearing in the logs:

```
##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please navigate to https://portal.azure.com/ and check if it was successfully deployed in Azure portal else Redeploy the App once again and Check..

Comment: Have you gone through this SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896255/azure-web-app-deploy-fails-with-cannot-read-property-updatestartupcommandandrun)

Comment: Yes, but that thread mentions `RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|5.0'
StartupCommand: 'dotnet {PROJECT_NAME}.dll'` ; But on this case, this app is PHP, there is no .NET involved on this Pipeline / Release.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dzctBvO.png - Make Sure you have updated the stack settings of your Linux Web App in Configuration > General Settings. For windows Apps it gets loaded in Environment variable when you set an Runtime Stack while creating Web App. For Linux apps and custom containers, App Service passes app settings to the container using the `--env` flag to set the environment variable in the container.

Comment: I checked now and this is the configuration that was applied: Stack: PHP  ; Major: PHP 7 ;  Minor: PHP 7.4

Comment: Upgrade it to the latest version

Comment: The customer app only works on this version. It does not work on PHP 8 yet. Even on PHP 8 the error is the same.