# updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack error azureweapp deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, .net-6.0

I use the yaml [here](https://subhankarsarkar.com/dot-net6-azure-web-app-deployment-using-azure-devops-pipeline/) for a .net 6 MVC site.

It work but the last part have an error. The site is deployed (working). I dont know where the error coming from.

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
 inputs:
    appType: webAppLinux
    azureSubscription: 'BlahBlah' #this is the name of the SPN
    appName: 'BasicMVC-1' #App Service's unique name
    package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
```

---

```
  Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
  ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined
```

Comment: Hi forX; there are a couple of older questions which discuss a similar error. Do either of these give you enough clues to figure out what's wrong in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69896255/174843 https://stackoverflow.com/q/70569215/174843

Comment: I'v seen the post, but the answer is for .net 5, I'm gonna retry.

Comment: Make Sure you have updated the stack settings of your Linux Web App in Configuration > General Settings. For windows Apps it gets loaded in Environment variable when you set an Runtime Stack while creating Web App. For Linux apps and custom containers, App Service passes app settings to the container using the --env flag to set the environment variable in the container.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/76AJE.png

Comment: Please navigate to http://portal.azure.com and check if it was successfully deployed in Azure portal and check if you are able to access the Application.

Comment: Please refer [Azure Web App task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app?view=azure-devops), it provides 2 optional parameters as arguments, that is: **runtimeStack** and **startUpCommand**. And they are relevant with Linux Web App. If appType == webAppLinux or you select Linux Web App in the app type selection option in the task,

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT the site is up, I can access the application. I check the confirugation and its good. I'm missing the startUpCommand in the yaml (or azure config), but I dont know what to add.

Comment: Please check this image ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3qDh.png)

azure portal --> Configuration--> General Settings-->Put a value in the `Startup Command`

Comment: I do pretest for upcoming tranfest site (and upgrade). I dont know what to put in statup command?

Comment: StartupCommand: 'dotnet Store.WebApi.dll' .

Comment: - task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    appType: webAppLinux
    azureSubscription: 'aaaaaaaaaa'
    appName: 'bbbbbbbbb'
    package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
    startUpCommand:  dotnet WebApplication1.dll

=> same error (Cannot read property 'updateStartupCommandAndRuntimeStack' of undefined)

Comment: Please refer  [YAML Deploy pipeline](https://www.kallemarjokorpi.fi/blog/deploy-net-6-web-app-to-linux-based-app-service.html) .
![enter image description here](https://cdn.buttercms.com/wWbp2fgeRweXubczBYwq)

Comment: Check the single and double quotes after the commands properly.

Comment: I did add "dotnet WebApplication1.dll" on startup command on azure portal. (no change) I'm looking at the application setting for linux in your link.

Comment: startUpCommand: 'dotnet WebApplication1.dll'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240956/discussion-between-harshithaveeramalla-mt-and-forx).

Comment: I'm experimenting the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: Have the same problem...

Comment: @forX Did you find a solution for this? My linux web app deploy still reports error but completes and works. Its extremely annoying to have to live with this big red error symbol for something that works fine, but maybe I just have to...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. For me it was caused by a combination of the App Service OS being Linux and the Azure DevOps service connection type using a publish profile for authentication. I changed my authentication method to Service Principal (automatic) and it stopped failing.

The only place I've found that explains the issue is here:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17988

> If we remove all the noise, it appears that appServiceUtility is only given a value when the authentication method is not “Publish profile”: